# How to schedule job by helidon MP?

Tags: jax-rs, helidon

Im Try to create schedule job sample, buy task dont execute.

what's wrong?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(FileService.class);
        return classes;
    }

}
```

```
public class FileService {

    public void schedulerFeature() throws InterruptedException {
        Scheduling.fixedRateBuilder()
                .delay(4)
                .initialDelay(2)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .task(inv -> {
                    System.out.println("Running in:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    System.out.println("Every 4 seconds an action, with an initial delay");
                })
                .build();

        Thread.sleep(12000);
    }

}
```

Im Try to create schedule job sample, buy task dont execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I revised my application and i had imported wrong maven lib. To schedule a job It is necessary import microprofile scheduling maven artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.microprofile.scheduling</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-microprofile-scheduling</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(FileService.class);
        return classes;
    }

}
```

```
import io.helidon.microprofile.scheduling.Scheduled;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;


/**
 * File service.
 */

@ApplicationScoped
public class FileService {

    @Scheduled("0/2 * * * * ? *")
    //@FixedRate(1)
    public void schedulerFeature()  {
        System.out.println("Running");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know which version of Helidon you're using, and hence I don't know which version of JAX-RS/Jakarta RESTful Web Services you're using.  For simplicity and brevity, I will assume you are using Helidon 3.x and [therefore](https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/blob/29c821a1abdbd2fef884e76209edfced1682ef86/dependencies/pom.xml#L75) Jakarta RESTful Web Services 3.0.0.

This is not a Helidon question, but rather a basic JAX-RS/Jakarta RESTful Web Services question.  You are really asking: "Why is my `FileService` class not instantiated by Jersey?"

Checking the [documentation for `Application#getClasses()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/ws/rs/core/application#getClasses()), we can see that it reads: "Get a set of root resource, provider and feature classes."  Your `FileService` class does not meet any of these requirements so it is simply ignored.

Guessing some more: I see you use the word "feature" in your example. This suggests that perhaps you want this class to actually be a true Jakarta RESTful Web Services [`Feature`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/ws/rs/core/feature).  Once again, the documentation here will tell you what you need to know to do next.

Comment: Hello user:20547477, if this answer solves your issue, please mark it as "answered". Thank you!